# Access: Setting a source object to another source object path

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying something crazy again. I would like to use this line of code:

```
Reports![PrntRep].SourceObject = Forms![Search Form]!Subform1.SourceObject
```

The source object of subform1 is dynamically depending on which query you need to search. I want the source of the report to be set to the same query, so that I don't need to make a bunch of different reports. 
It throws error 2465, application defined or object defined error.

Comment: What sort of issues are you running into when using that line of code?

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot to include that. Editing now.

Comment: Is [Search Form] open when you are trying to do this?

Comment: You need to make sure that `Forms![Search Form]!Subform1.SourceObject` is in scope. Can you verify that?

Comment: What is the scope of a form reference? I'm using it within the same database, but it is on the report, and it is initially used (the same reference) on Search Form

Comment: And yes [Search Form] is open. But focus is going to the report. There is a button on Search Form that opens the Report (it does this first) and then calls that line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A report does not have a `SourceObject` property.  That is the reason Access throws error #2465, *"Application-defined or object-defined error"* when you attempt to reference it.

Here is an Immediate window example from my system:

```vb
' first demonstrate the report is accessible ...
Debug.Print Reports!rptFoo.Name
rptFoo 
' now when referencing SourceObject ...
Debug.Print Reports!rptFoo.SourceObject ' <-- error 2465
```

Perhaps you want to alter the report's `RecordSource` instead:

```vb
' current RecordSource ...
Debug.Print Reports!rptFoo.RecordSource
SELECT rmy.id, rmy.reportDate, rmy.gainOrLoss FROM record_matYields AS rmy;
' change RecordSource to a saved query ...
Reports!rptFoo.RecordSource = "qryBar"
' confirm RecordSource was altered ...
Debug.Print Reports!rptFoo.RecordSource
qryBar
```

The report displayed 6 rows with the original `RecordSource`.  The saved query includes a `WHERE` condition which limits the results to only 2 of those rows.  So altering the `RecordSource` as above caused the report to display only those 2 rows without forcing the report into design mode, unlike the macro approach you mentioned in your comment.

Unfortunately I don't know enough about macros to help you fix yours.  I mostly avoid macros.

Comment: Ok, so that mostly fixed things. Now it successfully opens the report, but in design view. The macro is set to open the report in report view, but it goes to design view.

Comment: The issue there being I want to set the record source of the report to the source object of the subform, which varies depending on what the user is doing.

Comment: You know how to get the subform `SourceObject`: `Forms![Search Form]!Subform1.SourceObject`  Then use it for the report's `RecordSource`.  Where is the problem?

Comment: If I use that path to the source object, it goes to design view. The macro is also what calls the code from the button.